# error: array subscript is not an integer

Tags: c

```
 int row,col,i,j,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5,tmp6,tmp7;
 if(M==64&&N==64){
    for(row=0;row<N;row+=8){
        for(col=0;col<M;col+=8){
             for(j=0;j<2;j++){
                for(i=row;i<row+4;i++){
                    tmp0=A[i+4j][col+0];
                    tmp1=A[i+4j][col+1];
                    tmp2=A[i+4j][col+2];
                    tmp3=A[i+4j][col+3];
                    tmp4=A[i+4j][col+4];
                    tmp5=A[i+4j][col+5];
                    tmp6=A[i+4j][col+6];
                    tmp7=A[i+4j][col+7];

                    B[col+0+4j][i]=tmp0;
                    B[col+1+4j][i]=tmp1;
                    B[col+2+4j][i]=tmp2;
                    B[col+3+4j][i]=tmp3;
                    B[col+0+4j][i+4]=tmp4;
                    B[col+1+4j][i+4]=tmp5;
                    B[col+2+4j][i+4]=tmp6;
                    B[col+3+4j][i+4]=tmp7;

                }
```

but I got the code the error: array subscript is not an integer. But I don't know why.
Could someone have a look at and tell me why?
I do not think I use other type in the array besides int.

Comment: Replace all those `4j` with `4*j` and try again.

Comment: What is `4j` in all those lines?

Answer (score 3):

C does not support implicit multiplication like you commonly see in math. It obviously wouldn't work, since variable names can be more than one letter, it would create a huge amount of parsing confusion.

By your (implied) logic, an expression such as `row < N` should then be the same as `r * o * w < N`, which is clearly not what you really think.

Thus, multiplication must always be done explicitly using the `*` binary operator: `4j` is a parse error, you meant `4 * j`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int row,col,i,j,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5,tmp6,tmp7;
  if(M==64&&N==64){
    for(row=0;row<N;row+=8){
        for(col=0;col<M;col+=8){
         for(j=0;j<2;j++){
            for(i=row;i<row+4;i++){
                tmp0=A[i+4*j][col+0];
                tmp1=A[i+4*j][col+1];
                tmp2=A[i+4*j][col+2];
                tmp3=A[i+4*j][col+3];
                tmp4=A[i+4*j][col+4];
                tmp5=A[i+4*j][col+5];
                tmp6=A[i+4*j][col+6];
                tmp7=A[i+4*j][col+7];

                B[col+0+4*j][i]=tmp0;
                B[col+1+4*j][i]=tmp1;
                B[col+2+4*j][i]=tmp2;
                B[col+3+4*j][i]=tmp3;
                B[col+0+4*j][i+4]=tmp4;
                B[col+1+4*j][i+4]=tmp5;
                B[col+2+4*j][i+4]=tmp6;
                B[col+3+4*j][i+4]=tmp7;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp0=A[i+4j][col+0];
```

It should be

```
tmp0=A[i+4*j][col+0];
```

replace at all places

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication should be called explicitly: in your case, 4*j instead of 4j.